# In how many ways can $13$ identical objects be placed into squares such that no row remains empty?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I was inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4085348) I saw earlier today, to try to come up with a better *general* method, when there are more squares in each row, more rows, and more objects. Because basically the question in the link can be solved quite easily by counting by using lots of different methods because there aren't many squares or objects.

My question is, in the following diagram, how many ways can $13$ identical objects be placed into squares such that no row remains empty? [image]

To save you from counting, there are $9\times 2 + 13\times 1 + 17 \times 2 = 65$ squares total.

I feel like inclusion-exclusion can be used somehow, but I can't quite seem to get my thoughts onto paper for this problem...

And I'm more interested in innovative/clever counting techniques rather than pages upon pages of computation...

Comment: Where in the row they are placed is immaterial ?

Comment: @ true blue anil-  It *does* matter where they are placed in the row. Otherwise I think the answer would just be $\binom{8+5-1}{5} = \binom{12}{5},$ which is the number of ways of placing $13-5=8$ objects into $5$ bins (rows).

Answer (score 2):

This is still small enough to allow an inclusion-exclusion calculation:

$$\begin{align*}
&\binom{65}{13}-2\binom{48}{13}-\binom{52}{13}-2\binom{56}{13}\\
&\qquad+\binom{31}{13}+2\binom{35}{13}+4\binom{39}{13}+2\binom{43}{13}+\binom{47}{13}\\
&\qquad-\binom{18}{13}-2\binom{22}{13}-4\binom{26}{13}-2\binom{30}{13}-\binom{34}{13}\\
&\qquad+\binom{13}{13}+2\binom{17}{13}\\
&=\binom{65}{13}-4\,552\,426\,452\,267\\
&=11\,868\,647\,063\,013\,.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Whilst trying to absorb this answer, I noticed on your profile that you haven't asked any questions. Are you omniscient? Also this answer made me laugh at first. I think I understand the first line, but I'm lost by the 2nd line... . Please can you explain your calculation a bit?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Definitely not omniscient! The calculation starts with the number of ways to place $13$ objects in the $65$ squares, then subtracts the number of ways that leave at least one row empty, then adds the number of ways that leave at least two rows empty, and so on. I just now realized, however, that I made one assumption that you may not have intended: I assumed that each cell could accommodate only one object. If you meant to allow multiple objects in a cell, my answer is wrong.

Comment: No you are correct: I intended each square to accommodate exactly one object.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Oh, good: the other problem would be *really* messy!

Comment: Hmm, I get 11,868,647,063,013 by a different approach.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Your first formula is correct, so it is just an arithmetic error.  The correct result ends in 13 rather than 24.

Comment: @RobPratt: I’ll take your word for it; I used an online high precision calculator for that last subtraction, since my usual one hasn’t quite enough precision to handle $\binom{65}{13}$.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Binomial%5B65%2C13%5D-2Binomial%5B48%2C13%5D-Binomial%5B52%2C13%5D-2Binomial%5B56%2C13%5D%2BBinomial%5B31%2C13%5D%2B2Binomial%5B35%2C13%5D%2B4Binomial%5B39%2C13%5D%2B2Binomial%5B43%2C13%5D%2BBinomial%5B47%2C13%5D-Binomial%5B18%2C13%5D-2Binomial%5B22%2C13%5D-4Binomial%5B26%2C13%5D-2Binomial%5B30%2C13%5D-Binomial%5B34%2C13%5D%2BBinomial%5B13%2C13%5D%2B2Binomial%5B17%2C13%5D) with Binomial[] yields ...13.

Comment: The $4\,552\,426\,452\,256$ should instead be $4\,552\,426\,452\,267$.

Comment: @RobPratt: Ah, in that case I must have mistyped one of the smaller binomial coefficients when I did the calculation; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is:

$$[x^{13}]:((1+x)^9-1)^2((1+x)^{13}-1)((1+x)^{17}-1)^2$$

where $[x^{13}]$ means the coefficient of $x^{13}$ in the formula that follows.

This places at least one object in every row, and also counts the number of ways to place $k$ objects in a row using the binomial theorem.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B%28%281%2Bx%29%5E9-1%29%5E2%28%281%2Bx%29%5E%7B13%7D-1%29%28%281%2Bx%29%5E%7B17%7D-1%29%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C13%7D%5D) with SeriesCoefficient[] agrees.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.  Let $(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5)=(9,9,13,17,17)$, and let
\begin{align}
S&=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in \mathbb{Z}^5: \sum_{i=1}^5 x_i=13 \land \bigwedge_{i=1}^5 (1 \le x_i\le u_i)\right\} \\
&\leftrightarrow\left\{(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5)\in \mathbb{Z}^5: \sum_{i=1}^5 y_i=8 \land \bigwedge_{i=1}^5 (0 \le y_i\le u_i-1)\right\} \\
&=\left\{(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5)\in \mathbb{Z}_+^5: \sum_{i=1}^5 y_i=8\right\}.
\end{align}
Then $|S|=\binom{8+5-1}{5-1}=495$, and the desired count is
$$\sum_{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in S}\ \prod_{i=1}^5 \binom{u_i}{x_i} = 11,868,647,063,013$$